# Android: CountDownTimer set start value with button from EditText value

Tags: java, android, countdown

I've just started working with Android Studios and want to create a CountDownTimer with a setable Start value via Button Clickevent.
My Code so far:`

```
private static final String TAG = "MSchlanstedt";
private int number;
boolean status = true;
private CountDownTimer myTimer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    final EditText Time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
    final Button Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (status == true)
            {
                Button.setText("Stop");
                number = Integer.valueOf(Time.getText().toString())*1000;
                myTimer.start();
                status = false;
                Log.d(TAG, "Button.onClick():Start " + number);
            }else
            {
                myTimer.cancel();
                Button.setText("Start");
                Log.d(TAG, "Button.onClick():Stop " + number);
                status = true;
            }

        }
    });

    myTimer = new CountDownTimer(number,1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            Log.v(TAG,"CountDownTimer.onTick(): sUntilFinished: "+number+"/"+ millisUntilFinished /1000);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }
        public void onFinish()
        {
            Log.v(TAG,"CountDownTimer.onFinish()");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

...`

My problem is that the Button switches between the Text Start and Stop but the CountDown wont start with my int number. If i set the start value like 3000 it starts perfectly.

My Question is how do i get the value of my EditText as the Start Value of my CounterDown.

This is my first question on stackoverflow so please bei patient with me and my bad english.

Comment: please add your logcat

Comment: Change Edittext name. You shouldn't set name like "Time".

Comment: `private int number;` is automatically initialized as `0`. `myTimer = new CountDownTimer(number,1000) {...}` runs right after *setting* the OnClickListener. So `number` is `0` and `myTimer = new CountDownTimer(0,1000) {...}` is executed.

Comment: @Moeschie did you get it to work? You gave no feedback. Need further help / explanation?

Comment: @Marko Everything worked out just fine. Thank you Marko. I would upvote your post but i'm not allowed yet :D

Comment: @Moeschie It's fine. Just that it is working. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a method

```
private void showCountDownTimer(int number) {
    myTimer = new CountDownTimer(number, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {
                Log.v(TAG,"CountDownTimer.onTick(): sUntilFinished: "+number+"/"+ millisUntilFinished /1000);
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000));
            }
            public void onFinish()
            {
                Log.v(TAG,"CountDownTimer.onFinish()");
            }
    }.start();
}
```

And call it in `onClick`

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (status == true)
            {
                Button.setText("Stop");
                number = Integer.valueOf(Time.getText().toString())*1000;
                showCountDownTimer(number);
                status = false;
                Log.d(TAG, "Button.onClick():Start " + number);
            }else
            {
                myTimer.cancel();
                Button.setText("Start");
                Log.d(TAG, "Button.onClick():Stop " + number);
                status = true;
            }

        }
    });
```

**EXPLANATION:**

Because you initialize your `myTimer` (CountDownTimer) in onCreate, your default value for `number` is 0. You should initialize it on the fly (when you get the value).